# How to get the notification when the vaultState has updated in corda?

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

When we change a field or generate new output state for a Corda input state, is there any way to get the notification from vault to API.
Working on a state where we send the state to different parties when there is a status change of the state. So when the change has happened I want to develop a API which sends the notification to front end. I read we can used vaultTrackBy in corda. Is there any implementation in Java for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can get vault updates using vaultTrack function.

```
        final NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(args[0]);
        final CordaRPCClient client = new CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress, CordaRPCClientConfiguration.DEFAULT);

        // Can be amended in the com.example.Main file.
        final CordaRPCOps proxy = client.start("user1", "test").getProxy();

        // Grab all existing and future IOU states in the vault.
        final DataFeed<Vault.Page<IOUState>, Vault.Update<IOUState>> dataFeed = proxy.vaultTrack(IOUState.class);
        final Vault.Page<IOUState> snapshot = dataFeed.getSnapshot();
        final Observable<Vault.Update<IOUState>> updates = dataFeed.getUpdates();

        // Log the 'placed' IOUs and listen for new ones.
        snapshot.getStates().forEach(ExampleClientRPC::logState);
        updates.toBlocking().subscribe(update -> update.getProduced().forEach(state -> log.info("State: "+state)));
```

[Refer ExampleClientRPC class in cordapp-example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/main/java/com/example/client/ExampleClientRPC.java)

Comment: Thanks @Shivaganesh . But this updates call is not returning anything in the method. How can I capture and return as API response.